# Spring MVC - keep request parameters after redirect

Tags: java, spring, redirect, spring-mvc, request

I have a situation here where my frontend developer wants to add several parameters to every link. He needs those as parameters in the view where the link points to.

Each `@Controller` method will return Strings only. This is backed by a standard viewresolver using said String as viewname:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Whenever the Controller returns a `redirect:` however, the request parameters from the original request are dropped and he can not access them in the .jsp

Is there any neat way to ensure that even after `redirect:`'ing, the url parameters are present in the view which was redirected to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the solutions suggested by Bozho where not quite satisfactory for my needs, I wrote a filter which does exactly what I want. Not sure if any problems might occur in future cases but until then, feel free to use my implementation:

```
@Service
public class RedirectFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String queryString = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getQueryString();
    if (queryString != null) {
        RedirectAwareResponseWrapper res = new RedirectAwareResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
        chain.doFilter(request, res);
        if (res.isRedirected()) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(res.getLocation() + "?" + queryString);
        }
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

class RedirectAwareResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private boolean redirected = false;
    private String location;

    public RedirectAwareResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException {
        redirected = true;
        this.location = location;
        //IMPORTANT: don't call super() here
    }

    public boolean isRedirected() {
        return redirected;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a flash scope. It is already implemented from spring 3.1.RC1 onward - [see the request](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6464)

Comment: So I basically have to replace my `ModelMap` from the `@Controller` methods with `RedirectAttributesModelMap` and it should work?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how it work - perhaps the last comment by Rossen Stoyanchev should shed some light. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: From the first looks of it, it won't work. `RedirectAttributesModelMap` can not be used as a replacement to `ModelMap` because every value will be stored as a String representation. And most of my methods need to store and handle objects, passed via a ModelMap.

Comment: I'm currently looking at Interceptors. Intercept every request, extract request parameters and put them into the model. However, my frontend guy is accessing them in .jsp as ${param.nameOfTheUrlParam} which is standard. Not sure if this will still work.