# Spring MVC Easy way to pass @RequestParam annotated arguments to model

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to pass many @RequestParam annotated parameters to a Model object in an easy fashion.

Currently, I see two alternatives:

1. You can do it by hand (not so easy, example below)
2. You can create command objects for related parameters, and pass the object to your model.

I'm looking for a third way, which will do this for me automatically.

```
@RequestMapping
public void handle(@RequestParam String p1, @RequestParam String p2,
       @RequestParam String p3, @RequestParam String p4, Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("p1",p1);
     model.addAttribute("p2",p2);
     model.addAttribute("p3",p3);
     model.addAttribute("p4",p4);
}
```

The main reason I need this is to pass the parameters in a POST handler to flash attributes easily in case of an error.

**Update:** @ModelAttribute method (or specifying a bean without it, I think they're basically the same when you don't give @ModelAttribute a value) is actually the the second method I mentioned in the question. I'm looking for a way other than those I mentioned.

Comment: Might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686219/spring-mvc-keep-request-parameters-after-redirect

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use

```
@RequestMapping
public void handle(BeanDTO p1, Model model ){
    model.addAttribute("Bean",p1);
}
```

It takes all the parameters that match with the property beans and place them

```
classs BeanDTO {    
    private String p1;
    private String p2;
    private String p3;
}
```

Sorry withouth `@RequestBody`

Check this.   [Spring MVC bean mapping to HTTP GET request parameters similar to @BeanParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200979/spring-mvc-bean-mapping-to-http-get-request-parameters-similar-to-beanparam)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this way. Where as P is a java bean with the request parameters

```
@RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView handle(@ModelAttribute("p") P p) 
    {
      if (validationerror){
          return new ModelAndView("index","p",p);
      }
      return new ModelAndView("success");
    }
```